# How can i resolve a conflict in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code:

```
<script>var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<style>
.newsticker {
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
}

.newsticker li {
    color: #4e4e4e;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #2c8162;
}

.newsticker li:hover {
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>
<script>
    var count = 300;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update."; // watch for spelling
    }
    function news(){
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
    }
    $(function() {
    news();
    setInterval(function(){
      news();
    },30000)  // it will call every 1 min you can change it
    });
</script>
<br><br><span id="timer"></span><br><br>



<script language='JavaScript'>
$(function(){
 $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
});
/*!
 * liScroll 1.0
 * Examples and documentation at:
 * http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html
 * 2007-2010 Gian Carlo Mingati
 * Version: 1.0.2.1 (22-APRIL-2011)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Requires:
 * jQuery v1.2.x or later
 *
 */

jQuery.fn.liScroll = function(settings) {
  settings = jQuery.extend({
  travelocity: 0.10
  }, settings);  
  return this.each(function(){
    var $strip = jQuery(this);
    $strip.addClass("newsticker")
    var stripWidth = 1;
    $strip.find("li").each(function(i){
    stripWidth += jQuery(this, i).outerWidth(true); // thanks to Michael Haszprunar and Fabien Volpi
    });
    var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
    var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");        
    var containerWidth = $strip.parent().parent().width(); //a.k.a. 'mask' width  
    $strip.width(stripWidth);   
    var totalTravel = stripWidth+containerWidth;
    var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity; // thanks to Scott Waye  
    function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
    $strip.animate({left: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});
    }
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);    
    $strip.hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).stop();
    },
    function(){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
    var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
    scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
    });   
  }); 
};
</script>
<style>
/* liScroll styles */

.tickercontainer { /* the outer div with the black border */
border: 1px solid #000;
background: #fff;
width: 500px;
height: 27px;
margin: auto 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.tickercontainer .mask { /* that serves as a mask. so you get a sort of padding both left and right */
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 8px;
width: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul.newsticker { /* that's your list */
position: relative;
left: 500px;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}
ul.newsticker li {
float: left; /* important: display inline gives incorrect results when you check for elem's width */
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff;
}
ul.newsticker a {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0;
color: #ff0000;
font: bold 10px Verdana;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}
ul.newsticker span {
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
</style>

<ul id="ticker01">
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The first thing ...</a></li>
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">End up doing is ...</a></li>
 <li><span>10/10/2007</span><a href="#">The code that you ...</a></li>
 <!-- eccetera -->
</ul>
```

I'm using two different jquery newsticker examples:

The first end at:

```
<br><br><span id="timer"></span><br><br>
```

From there it's the second one.

I also added now in the top of my code this variable jQuery132:

```
<script>var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

How and where to use this variable ?

Comment: Please read the DOC: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/  I don't see why you would want to use $.noConflict() here.

Comment: A. Wolff i'm not sure if noConflict is the solution i'm not sure if tconflict is the problem. The problem is when i'm using this code the result is that the second part is making mass with the first part. The first part should be a timer count back and newsticker that scroll up take. The second pass should be not connected to the first one it should be below under the first one and make a marquee effect with text inside. You can see the problem it make in my site: http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html The question now if it's conflict or something else ?

Comment: It is more an issue related to multiple instances of plugin on same page, i don't know this plugin at all. You'd have better to ask them on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice [article regarding jQuery conflicts.](http://goo.gl/HacZxc)

Here is code:

```
<!-- load jQuery version 1.9.0 -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jQuery1_9 = $.noConflict(true);// Here you must need to pass true
                                    //else it will only free $ variable
                                    //and using jQuery with blow libraries
                                    //cause conflict
</script>

//you must load second library later after initializing
//first instance of version and freeup jQuery keyword
//else jQuery keyword will
//cause conflict it you uplaoded both files.

<!-- load jQuery version 1.10.0 -->
<script src="jquery-1.10.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jQuery1_10 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

//so now here $ and jQuery both cannot be used

//using $jQuery1_10 will call version 1.10.0 library code
$jQuery1_10( "div p" ).show();

//using $jQuery1_9 will call version 1.9.0 library code
$jQuery1_9( "div p" ).show();
```